# Bloomberg DDE Error when called from Python

Tags: python, dde, bloomberg

I am trying to send commands to Bloomberg Terminal using DDE.
Eg: to display the Microsoft page I can send:

```
<blp-1><CANCEL><CANCEL><HOME>MSFT<EQUITY><GO>
```

This works fine using a VBA library from EXCEL.  However I am trying to do the same from a Python script.  I am using the code from here (due to some restrictions I cannot use the more standard win32ui/dde python modules)

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577654-dde-client/

Messages are being passed to the Bloomberg Terminal but are not being interpreted correctly, Eg:

```
de = DDEClient('WinBlp', 'bbk')
de.execute('<blp-1><CANCEL><CANCEL><HOME>MSFT<EQUITY><GO>')
```

results in a Bloomberg window popping up, but with garbled text in the command area, something like

```
????A?????
```

Has anyone seem something like this?

Comment: Your organisation is paying an enormous fee for this service. I hope you have also asked bloomberg to comment on your error.

Comment: Can you imagine what the HELPHELP person would say if you asked them to help you fix a DDE problem?

Comment: @ashbyp HELPHELP are generally good - if the person does obviously not understand what you are talking about (which can happen), try again or ask to be forwarded to the API team and they are very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to change this line

> Initialize = get_winfunc("user32", "DdeInitializeW", UINT, (LPDWORD, DDECALLBACK, DWORD, DWORD))

to

> Initialize = get_winfunc("user32", "DdeInitializeA", UINT, (LPDWORD, DDECALLBACK, DWORD, DWORD))

From the MS documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648757(v=vs.85).aspx

DdeInitializeA is the ANSI version of the initializer,  rather than than the unicode.